# Capture still image from remote ip cam using avconv

Tags: linux, ubuntu, camera, libav

I'm attempting to capture a single still from an ip camera with avconv in ubuntu (server).

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the following command:

```
avconv -i rtsp://[USER]:[PASS]@[IPADDRESS]:554/11 -s 1920x1080 -f image2 foo.jpg
```

The error message I'm getting at the moment is:

```
avconv version 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 16 2015 13:19:10 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
[rtsp @ 0xb938e0] Could not find codec parameters (Video: h264, 1920x1080)
[rtsp @ 0xb938e0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://xxx:xxx@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/11':
  Metadata:
    title           : rtsp session
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264, 1920x1080, 90k tbn
    Stream #0.1: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
[buffer @ 0xb98520] Invalid pixel format string '-1'
Error opening filters!
```

In case it's of any value, I'm using a 2.0 MB IP Camera from Sinocam. I am able to view a live stream from the camera remotely using iSpy. However, I am unable to access and create an image still using avconv.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

```
 avconv -i rtsp://[user]:[pass]@[ip]:554/11 -f h264 -pix_fmt yuyv422 -video_size 1920x1080 screenshot.png
```

Creates the image file, however still fails:

```
[rtsp @ 0x1045a80] Could not find codec parameters (Video: h264, 1920x1080)
[rtsp @ 0x1045a80] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:admin@77.22.157.152:554/11':
  Metadata:
    title           : rtsp session
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264, 1920x1080, 90k tbn
    Stream #0.1: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
File 'screenshot.png' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[buffer @ 0x1035280] Invalid pixel format string '-1'
Error opening filters!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer lurking around online:

```
avconv -y -loglevel debug -stimeout 2 -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://[user]:[pass]@[IP]/11" -q:v 9 -s 1920x108 -vframes 1 test.png
```

Answer (score 1):

According to AVcon Documentation: https://libav.org/avconv.html#fbdev

The correct syntax for taking a screenshot (using Fbdev) is:

```
avconv -f fbdev -frames:v 1 -r 1 -i /dev/fb0 screenshot.jpeg
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply unfortunately: fbdev doesn't seem to work for rtsp:  ' Could not open framebuffer device: Unknown error -2
rtsp://[user]:[pass]@[ip]:554/11: No such file or directory'

Comment: question updated

Comment: Have you tried changing codec parameters? Please Try 1920x1088 instead. It may be a resolution issue.

Comment: sorry Is this your camera: http://www.szsinocam.com/china-onvif_4ch_1080p_wifi_nvr_ip_camera_dvr_1920_x_1080_for_ios_android-2134237.html for it says on description resolution is 1280*720. Even if its not the exact model I would try 1280*720 as well

Comment: this is the camera: http://www.tvc-mall.com/details/SINOCAM-HD-1080P-2-0MP-Outdoor-IR-IP-Camera-20m-IR-3-6mm-Lens-w-P2P-Bracket-SN-IPC-5001C-EU-Plug-White-84000296B/